Converting a potential DST datetime to "normal" time when DST ends
I'm implementing conversion functions to and from DST datetimes. I have knowledge of when DST starts and ends. Going from "normal" time to DST is easy enough. Just add an hour to the normal time, essentially skipping that hour (e.g. from 2:00 AM to 3:00 AM). However, going the other way, from DST back to "normal" time, causes me lots of headaches.
The problem is, that if I pass in a datetime with a time between 3:00 and 3:59 AM that can mean either 3:00 - 3:59 AM in DST, in which case I would have to subtract one hour, or 3:00 - 3:59 AM is already in normal time, in which case I would not alter the time.
Further complicating things is that we're using our own date, time and datetime classes with the latter being a composite of the first two, and the time class goes from 0:00 to 36:00 hours (noon the next day).
I've written the following functions, but to be honest, I don't have much confidence in FromDST().
bool IsDST(const TRDateTime& dt)
{
  TRDateTime dta = dt.Adjusted(); // adjust from potential 36 hrs to 24 hrs
  if (currentDSTPeriod == std::make_pair(TRDateTime(), TRDateTime()))
    return false;
  if (dta.date < currentDSTPeriod.first.date || dta.date > currentDSTPeriod.second.date)
    return false;
  if (dta.date == currentDSTPeriod.first.date && dta.time < currentDSTPeriod.first.time)
    return false;
  if (dta.date == currentDSTPeriod.second.date && dta.time >= currentDSTPeriod.second.time)
    return false;
  return true;
}

bool ToDST(TRDateTime& dt)
{
  if (IsDST(dt) || dt.time.MinuteSerial() < TIME_24H)
    return false;
  dt += 60;
  return true;
}

bool FromDST(TRDateTime& dt)
{
  if (!IsDST(dt) && dt.time.MinuteSerial() >= TIME_24H)
    return false;
  dt -= 60;
  return true;
}

I'd really like some input. I have of course checked for existing answers, but I haven't found one that helps in my particular situation.
Perhaps it would be a good idea to explain how these functions are going to be used.
The idea is that all data will be stored in the database in "normal" (i.e. standard or local) datetime. To get that datetime both DST and a kind of "time zone" offset (with regard to the main location of the company) will be applied.
If that data would only be shown to the user I could simply add an hour depending on whether or not DST was in effect. However, at remote locations users will need to be able to input dates and times in their local time and that data needs to be converted to the standard datetime which is then stored.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
